# Authenticating on github using featherjs results in a strange behavior

Tags: feathersjs

I'm trying to authenticate using github.

I configured properly the callback, successRedirect and failureRedirect.

The successRedirect page is called. In this page I try to call the authenticate function.

```
client.authenticate({
      strategy: 'github'
    })
```

The promise resolve with a token but when I try to access a secured service, it returns an error. Then If I try to retry to access a second time to the service, it works.

Can someone explain me or provide me a working example.

My code:

```
const hello = client.service('hello');

function getVal(iter) {
  console.log("Iter " + iter)

  hello.get(1, {}).then((data) => {
    console.log('User is logged');
    console.dir(data)
  }, (error) => {
    console.dir(error)
    getVal(iter + 1)
  })
}

client.authenticate({
  strategy: 'github'
}).then((token) => {
  console.dir(token)
  getVal(0)
}, (error) => console.dir(error));
```

In the logs I see that the first call to the service fails with an authentication error but not the second while I'm supposed to be logged (because it's in the configured success redirection)

My logs:

```
Object { accessToken: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6ImFjY2…" }

Iter 0
{
className: "not-authenticated"
code: 401
……
}
Iter 1
User is logged
{…}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [oAuth2 client usage API](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/oauth2.html#client-usage) shows that instead of calling `authenticate` you just have to link the user to `/auth/github` to kick of the oAuth flow:

```
<a href="/auth/github" class="button">Login With GitHub</a>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for helping me. 

My understanding if I must then start the oAuth flow with the link as you said. But, prior to service api call (that require an authorization) I need to call authenticate otherwise the promise resolves in a 401. 

The result of authenticate can help me knowing if the user is authenticated against the oAuth provider (github in my case) and display the login button accordingly.